# Flutter build fail when running app on ios emulator to try an initialise it for Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, ios, flutter

It's perfectly fine when I run android. This is the error that I get when I run my app on iOS:

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           13.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
/Users/obakengmogafe/AndroidStudioProjects/nghbrly004/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:10:9: fatal error: module 'cloud_firestore' not found
@import cloud_firestore;
~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro.

Comment: How did you solve it?